# Read user input while looping through find results using read

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using the following statement in a bash script to iterate through the results of find:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.mkv -o -iname \*.mp4 \) | while read line; do
```

Now the problem is I can't ask for user input using "read" in this loop as it will give me the next line from the the find results.

```
read mainmenuinput
```

will give me the next filename instead of waiting for user input.

How can I work around this?

Thanks,
rayfun

Comment: Is the input required for every file or just once at the beginning? Also be careful regarding spaces (or other "odd" characters) in filenames - it will break your `read`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different file descriptor for the `find` results, if you use a redirection from a process substitution into the loop:

```bsh
# this reads from fd 3
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
    # this reads from fd 0 (stdin)
    read -p "Enter your input" main_menu_input
    # .. do stuff
done 3< <(
    find ... 
)
```

This harms readability a bit as the find command shows up at the bottom, but it gives you the maximum flexibility wrt file descriptors. Additionally, the while loop is *not* run in a subshell due to piping, so if you're setting variables in the while loop that you rely on in code following the loop, you're now OK.

Comment: How would I apply your answer to this? Still learning shell scripting :-/
`find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.mkv -o -iname \*.mp4 \) | while read line; do
    read mainmenuinput
done`

Comment: That's exactly what I demonstrated.

Comment: In my scenario I have a function called "pause", that will read input from the user asking whether to continue. I'm calling that function from multiple places within my find result processing. So I'd like to read input multiple times within that find | while; do construct. Any idea how to achieve that? Sorry I didn't explain in more detail. Thank you!

Comment: I truly don't understand what you're asking me. It seems like you're asking your question to me over and over. I've answered it. Do you have any specific questions about my answer?